# How do I create a pointer to an existing unsigned long?

Tags: c, pointers

If I write the following C code:

```c
unsigned long l = 0UL;
unsigned long *lPtr = ...
```

How do I make *lPtr point to the value of l?

Thank you for your help!

I tried

```
unsigned long *fPtr = *(&l);
```

But I received the warning:

> warning: initialization of ‘long unsigned int *’ from ‘long unsigned int’ makes pointer from integer without a cast

Comment: "fPtr = &l" will work

Comment: I presume you meant you tried `*(&l)`, but that's wrong because the `*` and the `&` cancel out, producing only `l`.

Answer (score 1):

`&` creates a pointer to its operand, so you need `&l`.

```c
unsigned long l = 123UL;
unsigned long *lPtr = &l;

printf( "%lu\n", *lPtr );  // 123

*lPtr = 456UL;

printf( "%lu\n", l );      // 456
```

Comment: Note that the `UL` suffixes aren't necessary here. The values would fit nicely in an `int`, and we don't care about the type of the literal.  I used them for consistency with the OP.